# What is the simplest way to handle vectors in Sympy?

Tags: sympy

I was interested in using Sympy for physics problems, which often involve vectors. Looking at the docstring for the symbols function, I saw:

" If an iterable container is needed for a single symbol, set the `seq`
argument to `True` or terminate the symbol name with a comma::"

This seemed like solution but it was not. The answer below, Matrix, seems better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood what the seq argument is for. It's to always return a tuple:

```
In [3]: symbols('x, y')
Out[3]: (x, y)

In [4]: symbols('x')
Out[4]: x

In [5]: symbols('x', seq=True)
Out[5]: (x,)
```

The `seq=True` argument means that you always get a tuple of symbols even if only one symbol is returned. That's different from saying that it returns a symbol representing a sequence/list.

Perhaps what you want is `MatrixSymbol`:

```
In [6]: M = MatrixSymbol('M', 3, 1)

In [7]: M
Out[7]: M

In [8]: M.as_explicit()
Out[8]: 
Matrix([
[M[0, 0]],
[M[1, 0]],
[M[2, 0]]])
```

Comment: I would like some clarification about how seq=True and MatrixSymbol are used. If seq=True gives you a list with only one element, and lists are immutable, what is the advantage of having a list of one rather than an atomic symbol?

Comment: The advantage is if you are writing code that needs to work with an arbitrary number of symbols. In that case it is more useful to have `symbols` always return a tuple even if sometimes it is only of length 1. If you know that you only want one symbol then you can just use `Symbol`.